# Autocomplete "smart"

Tags: elasticsearch

Should I build an autocomplete "smart" in the sense that for every result must be worn behind a series of information.

For example:

I am looking for "bologna" and I have to run a query (or more than one, I was looking for a way to make it as little as possible) where "bologna" is searched in the fields "name", "locality" and "region".

If it is found, necessary to count how many structures there are in "bologna".

This is the database schema:

```
index:   
analysis:   
    analyzer:
        custom_search_analyzer:
            type: custom
            tokenizer: standard
            filter   : [standard, snowball, lowercase, asciifolding]
        custom_index_analyzer:
            type: custom
            tokenizer: standard
            filter   : [standard, snowball, lowercase, asciifolding, custom_filter]
    filter:
        custom_filter:
            type: edgeNGram
            side: front
            min_gram: 1
            max_gram: 20

{
 "structure": {
   "properties": {
     "name": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"},
     "locality": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"},
     "province": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"},
     "region": {"type": "string", "search_analyzer": "custom_search_analyzer", "index_analyzer": "custom_index_analyzer"}
   }
 }
}
```

Obviously I could do this on the server side, for example with php with a loop, but the answer would be very slow and was frustrated all the speed of elasticsearch.

At this point I wonder how I could do this.

Comment: Did you have a look at the completion suggester? http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/

Comment: Yes, I have seen suggest to elasticsearch, but as I stated in the question, I need more data than the simple auto-completion in the search. This thing with the suggest to elasticsearch is not possible. Or at least I don't know the way.

Comment: Did not completely understand what you are asking. Does `payloads` in completion suggester solve your problem? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: No, `payloads` no use for my problem. 
What I need to do is to look for such as the name of a city and return more than suggest the name of the city, the number of structures that are in that city.

Comment: Did aggregations solve your problem?

Comment: I wonder if question title shouldn't be "How to perform aggregations?".

Comment: What do you mean by "how many structures "

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this guide](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams) succesfully, it addresses the multi-field requirement you mentioned.